# sass modules aliased paths not working when deploying on digitalocean

Tags: typescript, sass, next.js

I have a project I am attempting to deploy on **DigitalOcean** (I'm unsure if the platform matters, but I thought it may be worth mentioning just in case).

In this project, I am making use of aliased `paths` specified in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
    "@Components/*": ["App/Components/*"],
    "@Functions/*": ["App/Functions/*"],
    "@Types/*": ["App/Types/*"],
    "@Styles/*": ["Imports/Styles/*"]
}
```

When building the project locally, everything works completely fine (even for the **SASS** imports). However, when building on a *deployed* server (such as a **DigitalOcean App Platform**), I will receive the error:

```
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/App/Components/Module/Footer.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@Styles/Module/Footer.module.scss' in '/workspace/src/App/Components/Module'

Import trace for requested module:
./src/pages/_app.tsx
```

This is my file structure (for `Footer.tsx`):

```
node_modules
...
tsconfig.json
src
 |-- App
 | |-- Components
 |   |-- Module
 |     |-- Footer.tsx
 |-- Imports
 | |-- Styles
 |   |-- Module
 |     |-- Footer.module.scss
```

This happens for multiple files and only when importing using the alias `@Styles/*` (`@Components/*`, `@Functions/*`, `@Types/*` are all fine).

Is there some sort of extra configuration I need to do for stylesheets and aliased imports?

Before you ask, **YES** I have *triple-checked* that the file structure and imports are correct.

```
/* src/App/Components/Module/Footer.tsx */
import styles from "@Styles/Module/Footer.module.scss";
```